# Did Europeans ever trade eye aids (telescopes, spyglass, etc) to the Native Americans (1608 - 1850)?

Tags: native-americans, trade, colonial-america

Did Europeans ever trade telescopes to the Native Americans? Did they ever attempt to do so?

**Edit:** changing this to any kind of eye aids. Telescopes, spyglass, binoculars, monocles, magnifying glasses, etc. And yes the time is actually 1608 onwards. Since we need a end time too, I picked the arbitrary year of 1850.

Did they also warn them not to point it directly at the sun? Or maybe did they give them solar filters too? (using a telescope on the sun will instantly fry your eye, as in, melt it. This is where pirate eye patches originally came from when someone forgot to apply the solar filter.)

Comment: [Yes, here is a photo](https://indiancountrymedianetwork.com/news/the-native-astronomer/) of a Native American with a telescope. Also, when I was on a reservation in Northern Arizona, I saw some families out with telescopes one night. They were looking at the stars.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: are we talking about astronomy telescopes or would that include spyglasses/monoculars? The existing answer seems to mix both, but spyglasses would typically not be used for astronomy

Comment: @CGCampbell Yes. Edited that and made it any kind of eye aid. Hopefully I will get no more downvotes/closevotes.

Comment: @SJuan76 I chaged the title to include any kind of eye aid. AFAIK, spyglasses and any kind of magnifier should not be pointed at the sun anyway.

Comment: Without and end-date, the answer is trivially "yes".

Comment: @DrZ214 you should not look at the sun even with the naked eye, anyway, so I do not think it makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @SJuan76 Actually, looking at the Sun with a spyglass or telescope will instantly fry your eye (if there's no filter). That's where pirate eyepatches originally came from. With the naked eye, the UV light will slowly damage you. So there is a difference. This is why I was concerned if the Europeans explained/warned of this.

Comment: The remark about warning them seems a little condescensing. Native Americans aren't stupid or of lower intelligence than Europeans.  Even if their cultures didn't originally develop telescopes, they can easily figure out that "look directly at Sun with telescope" = "blind" and start spreading word on telescope safety.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Don't you think it would be more condescending to not give the warning at all? They might surmise that looking at the sun would only show a big white light ("blind"), but why are you assuming they would know their eyes would be burned right out of their sockets?

Comment: @StevenBurnap I picked an arbitrary end date of 1850 and edited the OP.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Ginasius It was probably because my original version didn't specify an end date, and I put the start date as 1492 instead of 1608, which is when the telescope was actually invented. You can see the original version by clicking "edited Feb 21 '17 at 0:35" and scroll all the way down.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly, maybe.  My initial thought was that a telescope would be much too valuable as a trade item.  Some research did come up with an item that was shown in an antique catalog, listed as:

> Blackfoot Telescope. 19th c. brass telescope covered with beadwork...

image can be seen at the link:

- [Warman's Antiques & Collectibles 2013 Price Guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VzbrvIpMu0C&pg=PT592&dq=american%20indian%20spy%20glass&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifq_ubxJzSAhVp64MKHRBoDr0Q6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q&f=false), by Zac
  Bissonnette

So this shows 19th century Native Americans in possession of a spyglass, but not how they came into possession of the item.

---

- Found another listed as [Crow Telescope with Beaded Buffalo Hide
  Case](https://auctions.bidsquare.com/view-auctions/catalog/id/1935/lot/664167)
  from the sights description:

> Description: Crow Telescope with Beaded Buffalo Hide Case, c. 1870s,
>   with diagonal designs, thick fringe with large trade beads at one end,
>   and detailed with red stroud cloth, lg. 8 in.
>
> Provenance: Ex Bud Lake Crow collection.

(this item sold at auction for $3690)

- and another here: [www.splendidheritage.com](http://www.splendidheritage.com/DataPages/FCTEL1407.html), also listed as being from the [Crow Nation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow_Nation)

Comment: An antique telescope with native-American style decoration does not prove anything: it is not known who was the owner of this telescope.

Comment: The 2nd link, Crow Telescope with Beaded Buffalo Hide Case, is not working for me. Can anyone summarize it?

Comment: updated with description of second link scope

Comment: Would anyone like to fund a kickstarter program for a "Smartphone with Celtic knotwork design and paired smartwatch built in to a Claddagh ring" to help me prove that medieval Irish people had intelligent mobile devices?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Digging 3m deep in suburban London revealed an old copper-wire system that proves that Englishmen were using telephones more than one century ago. But then archeologists dug 15m deep in Ireland and found no glass-fiber network at all, so the obvious conclusion is that Irishmen were already using Wi-Fi in the 8th century.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. It is possible that European settlers could have given optical devices to the Native Americans, though the indigenous peoples of the new world would have had little practical use for these devices. Few, if any, tribes had written language, thus the convex lenses for farsightedness would have been useless to those people. Glasses for nearsightedness could have been useful to native Americans, though it wasn't as common a condition as it is nowadays. As for telescopes and spyglasses, they may have been a bit more useful to the native tribes, as it would have helped them hunt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).